# Is there a way to get several s3 aws markers beforehand?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I'd like to load an s3 storage by querying. And let's say I have 40000 pages in the bucket waiting for me, 1000 objects per page. I know I'll be querying full pages each time. Is there a way to get a list of markers beforehand to run requests in parallel? So that I could split up those 40000 pages between let's say 8 threads instead of doing it sequentially.

Comment: No, the next token can only be retrieved from listing the page it's for.  If you want a quick list of the items, you can setup a S3 Inventory report.

Comment: @Anon Coward could you please post it as an answer? I'll mark it as answered